# how to reduce qtgui4.dll's size?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using qt4 on windows to draw some easy ui,I've compile it with vs2010 and I get the qtcore4.dll(2.43mb) and qtgui4.dll(8.04mb).Following is my configure params:

```
configure -platform win32-msvc2010 -fast -release -opensource -shared -qt-zlib
-qt-libpng -qt-libmng -qt-libtiff -qt-libjpeg -no-qt3support -no-webkit -no-
phonon -no-script -no-scripttools -qt-style-windowsxp -qt-style-windowsvista -
nomake examples -nomake docs -nomake demos
```

I know there is tool named "qconfig" which can do a precise custom configuration.But that seems just available on embedded system.What should I do to reduce the size of my qt program? Or there are some other stable、documented and easy-to-use UIframes of c++ on window like qt?

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to reduce it by much; 8.04MB is already pretty small by Qt's standards.  If you're really keen on minimizing Qt's library size, however, you might consider upgrading to Qt 5.8.0; they've spent some time on new tools ("Qt Lite") that allow you to reduce Qt's distribution footprint, for that version:  https://blog.qt.io/blog/2017/01/23/qt-5-8-released/

Comment: Have you considered static linking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom compilation on Qt version 5.7 and below doesn't help much.

static compilation upon my test did not produce much lower binary, even with all possible optimization and strip.

Qt5.8 however said the following:

> Qt 5.8 comes with a rewritten configuration system, that allows for easy customisation of your Qt build. The main focus of this feature is for the Device Creation, but it can also be used to tailor a Qt build for mobile or desktop. The system allows removing individual pieces of functionality and APIs from Qt, thus creating a more lightweight set of libraries for deployment.

[New Feature Qt5.8](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Features_in_Qt_5.8)

And thus porting to Qt5.8 should be quite easy and may reduce your total package size.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you should fit in a single 5MB executable: a statically linked, upx-compressed Qt 4.8 hello world using the gui and network modules, including OpenSLL and statically linked C++ runtime, compiled with VS2012 or newer using LTCG. Such an executable has no dependencies on anything except Windows itself - you don't even need to install the MSVC runtime. That's a few times smaller than what you currently have. No changes/feature selections need to be done to Qt itself.